# jQuery selecting dynamic ID

Tags: jquery, html

I need to select dynamic id using JQuery, and once I select it then I need to do some action on it.

```
<input id="content_photos_attributes_1355755712119_image"   name="content[photos_attributes][1355755712119][image]" size="30" type="file">
```

The HTML contains both ID and Name attribute. I dont care which one I can select as long it is selected.
This is what I have tried so far, without success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery("#add_photo_product").click(function() {

alert("Handler foooor .click() called.");

//var field = $("input[id *= 'content_photos_attributes_']");
var field = $('input[name*="content"]');
alert (field);

});
```

The first selector works, and I can grab it easily. As soon as it is executed, then DOM is populated with the one that I can get hold of (Under HTML code).

I have tried various combinations, but it is always null.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting Dynamic ID JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917734/selecting-dynamic-id-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replace this

```
   jQuery("#add_photo_product").click(function() {
```

by this

```
   jQuery("#content_photos_attributes_1355755712119_image").click(function() {
```

you are not making the `id` which is shown in your html code

to run you your test better do easy alert just to test if it works

like that

```
    alert(1);     // this will alert 1
```

EDIT2>

if you have the id like a variable then you can also do it like that

```
   var myid = "content_photos_attributes_"+your_variable+"_image" ;
             // note that your_variable is this which generates 1355755712119 

    jQuery("#"+myid).click(function() {
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Goodmood If I use your second example, it will not work since that number is always dynamic, however the text is always the same. So I need solutkon for this: jQuery("#content_photos_attributes_XXXXXXXXXXX_image").click(function() {   X is content that is akways changed. How can I get control over that item and run onclick on it?  Thanks!

Comment: can u give me what is this XXX ?what is this variable .?

Answer (score 2):

You ran `jQuery.noConflict()`, which means $ is not jQuery. Try using `jQuery` instead of `$`.