# Selecting Dynamic ID JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I need to select dynamic id using JQuery, and once I select it then I need to do some action on it. This is the HTML that I have:

```
<input id="content_photos_attributes_1355755712119_image"   name="content[photos_attributes][1355755712119][image]" size="30" type="file">
```

Please note the id value, text is always the same however the number changes (I do not have control over that change).

What I need to do is to create on click for that element. This is what I got so far, and it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

  jQuery("input[id *= 'content_photos_attributes_']").click(function() {

  alert("Image deletion is clicked");
});
</script>
```

It really makes no difference whether I select that element by ID or by its name.

Comment: Your code works. http://jsfiddle.net/2SLpB/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As i see this it should be in the `$(document).ready();` handler and its a dynamic id so for this you have to use `.on()` handler to select the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'input[id^="content_photos_attributes_"]', function() {
       alert("Image deletion is clicked");
    });
});
```

try this and see if helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the *starts with* `^=` selector:

```
$("input[id^='content_photos_attributes_']").click(function() {
    alert("Image deletion is clicked");
});
```

Also you don't need the quotes inside the attribute comparison unless you're having the dot '.' character. This would also work:

```
$("input[id^=content_photos_attributes_]").click(function() {
    alert("Image deletion is clicked");
});
```

Comment: Yeah the issue has been that DOM is not yet loaded when your jQuery is executing